# How to convert UInt to Int in swift?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, int, uint

I need to convert a variable from NSUInt to Int to pass it as argument to allocate.

I tried initializing with Int() but the compiler refuses `cannot invoke initializer for type 'int' with an argument of type '(UInt?)'`

this is the variable: `NSUInteger count`
this is the call to allocate`let outPut = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: count)`

Without the conversion the compiler generates this error: 
`cannot convert value of type 'UInt?' to expected argument type 'Int'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it is optional, you need to unwrap it

```
var x: UInt?

if let z = x {
    let y = Int(exactly: z) 
}
```

Note that `Int(exactly:)` returns an optional as well so you might want to use a `guard` statement or another `if let...`

*Update, as pointed out by vacawama Int(z) might crash*

Comment: This will crash if `x` is too big for an `Int`.  I recommend `if let z = x, let y = Int(exactly: z) {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bit pattern initialiser.

```
let unsignedInt = Int(bitPattern: UInt)
```

But this will not take care overflow situations.